# Set Delete Line shortcut in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, shortcuts, text-editors, text-editing

How can I set `Delete Line` shortcut in Notepad++?

I would like to be able to delete the whole line at which mн carriage is by pressing `Ctrl + D`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031741/delete-line-without-adding-to-clipboard
changed to correct difference in my version of NPP but should be close to line 89 or 90.

> By default Ctrl + Shift + L however you can change it to something
>   like Shift + Del by going to the Settings menu, Shortcut Mapper, click
>   on the Scintilla commands tab, scroll to command 89, "SCI_LINEDELETE"
>   and adjust the shortcut from there. Valid as of Notepad++ 6.9.1